# How many ways may 9 different chocolate bars be given to 3 children’s such that each child gets 3 chocolate bars? Assume order is important

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many ways may 9 different chocolate bars be given to 3 children’s such that each child gets 3 chocolate bars? Assume order is important.

I’m not sure how to solve this question or where to even start ive tried a few ways but don’t get the correct answer

Comment: Did you try searching the site for a similar question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $\binom{ 9}{3, 3, 3} = \frac{ 9!} { 3! 3! 3!} = 1680 $ ways to distribute 9 distinct chocolate bars to the 3 children, each receiving 3 of them. This is the [Multinomial theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/multinomial-theorem/).

If you care about the order, then you can multiply by the order that you care about (IE order just to an individual child, or order of all 9).

Comment: You meant to write $\binom{9}{3, 3, 3}$.

Comment: Should we be encouraging OPs to make zero effort?

Comment: @almagest I've given up on that on MSE, esp with new users. I'm giving the numerical answer, along with a link that they can refer to if they are interested.

Comment: @CalvinLin Maybe you are right. I oscillate! Incidentally, I like the link (I had not noticed the brilliant/wiki before.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that the division among the three children is just dust in the eyes if the order is important. Let me unpack.

Let's call the chocolate bars: `1`, `2`, ..., `9`.

Suppose given a list of these bars you give the first three to the first kid, second three to the second kid, last three to the third kid. Let's depict it this way:

`c1 c2 c3 | c4 c5 c6 | c7 c8 c9`,

where `ci` is the `i`th chocolate bar. If the order is important, i.e.

`1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9`

and

`2 1 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9`

count as two different ways of giving out bars, then the question really is: "How many permutations of the 9 chocolate bars exist?". And the answer is `9!`.

If this is not the answer, then the question should be better posed.

Comment: The answer seems to be incorrect...The order of the permutation doesn't matter when the chocolate is handed over to a child... it matters as long as the distribution was among the different. Moreover, three children are not the same... They should be considered different entities.

Comment: They are different entities. If the order DOES NOT matter, then
`1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9` is indifferent from `2 1 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9`. Which means that you have to divide `9!` by `(3!)^3`, where the cube comes from the permutations for each of the three kids, as for @calvin's answer.

Again, I believe the question was ill-posed.